# Unable to read .npz file in python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I created an npz(compressed file) using following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np    # for mathematical operations
from keras.preprocessing import image   # for preprocessing the images

anomoly_data = pd.read_csv('/code_data/anomoly_data.csv')
f = open('/code_data/anomoly_data.npz', 'wb')
for i in tqdm(range(anomoly_data.shape[0])):
    img = image.load_img(anomoly_data['image'][i], target_size=(224,224,3))
    # converting it to array
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    # normalizing the pixel value
    img = img/255
    np.savez_compressed(f, img)
f.close()
```

the compressed file has size of 52GBs which indicates that it contains data of all the images.
in anomoly_data.csv i have the path for each image and entries in .csv are

```
188604
```

and now i'm trying to read the data of all the images from compressed using following code:

```
f=open("/code_data/anomoly_data.npz","rb")
for i in tqdm(range(anomoly_data.shape[0])):
    img=np.load(f)
    print(img)
```

and then I get this error telling me that there is only one ndarray in the compressed file, Error:

```
<numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at 0x7fdfd1d437c0>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-29b2878e9fe9> in <module>
      1 f=open("/code_data/anomoly_data.npz","rb")
      2 for i in range(anomoly_data.shape[0]):
----> 3     img=np.load(f)
      4     print(img)
      5 

~/Programs/Anaconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
    442             # Try a pickle
    443             if not allow_pickle:
--> 444                 raise ValueError("Cannot load file containing pickled data "
    445                                  "when allow_pickle=False")
    446             try:

ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False
```

but i get data of only one array which suggests that there is either data of only one image or it is deformed. implying that compressed file is not genrated properly.
is there any better way to do this?

Comment: `np.save` has an example of writing and loading a couple of arrays to one file.  Using that model you should be able to save your images in a loop.  `np.savez` creates a `zip` archive, so I don't know if this repeated save approach works there.  I haven't seen or tested a working example.

Comment: @hpaulj i only load 5 images data into file using, `np.save`,`np.savez`,`np.savez__compressed` and size comparision is 3MB,3MB and 700KB respectively.I am working on large dataset so using `np.save` or `np.savez` consume huge memory space around 200GB.

Comment: Which is more important, size or functionality?  As far as I know `compressed` is another layer on top of the `zip` archive.  I don't  know if it makes access harder or not. Get the code working with a few arrays; big size can come later.

Comment: I think you need to experiment with `np.save` of just one image.  Take small steps.

Comment: obviously the functionality is more important.Thanks alot.